# Programming algorithm for a non-brute force method to solve the equation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, equation

What can be a good programming algorithm to solve the following equation, other than the brute force method?

Find all x, y and z for n=100;

```
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = n;
```

x, y, z should be positive integers.

Comment: Is `^` an exponentiation or a bitwise XOR?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in linear time with respect to n:

```
int x, y, z;
int n = 1000;
int tests = 0;
int solutions = 0;
// loop through all possible x values
for(x = 1; x * x * 3 <= n; x++)
{
    // compute target sum of y^2 + z^2
    int m = n - x * x;
    for(y = x; y * y * 2 <= m; y++)
    {
        tests++;
        // compute z and check if it's an integer:
        z = (int)(Math.sqrt(m - (y * y)));
        if((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z) == n)
        {
            System.out.println(""+x+" "+y+" "+z);
            solutions++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(tests);
System.out.println(solutions);
```

It removes one inner loop compared to the brute force solution, by calculating the necessary value of z given x and y and checking if it is integer.

Number of tests required and solutions found for values of n:

```
 n          tests       solutions
 5000       1081        8
 500000     108749      45
 50000000   10879762    232
```

There doesn't seem to be any way of getting rid of the outer loop, because you need to loop through multiple solutions, but you can "early out" and avoid the inner looop by checking if m is [the sum of two squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787321/how-to-determine-whether-a-number-can-be-written-as-a-sum-of-two-squares)

This is a simple implementation of the linked algorithm, however there are much more advanced factorization algorithms (e.g. Pollard's rho):

```
public static boolean isSumOfTwoSquares(int m)
{
    for(int i = 2; i * i <= m; i++)
    {
        int exponent = 0;
        while(m % i == 0)
        {
            m /= i;
            exponent++;
        }
        if((m % 4 == 3) && ((exponent & 1) != 0))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can wrap your inner loop in this check:

```
if(isSumOfTwoSquares(m))
```

Results:

```
 n          tests       solutions
 5000       777         8
 500000     72162       45
 50000000   6511184     232
```

Given a fast enough `isSumOfTwoSquares` function, this might come out ahead. Unlike the simpler algorithm without the early out, the number of tests is much more sensitive to the value of n.

Both the algorithm have the constraint the x <= y <= z. I you want all solutions without this constraint you can permute the solutions, there will be 6 (3!) for each constrained solution.

Comment: Assuming x ≤ y ≤ z, you might be able to do this a bit quicker if you start with the largest number first. So z is in the range from sqrt (n/3) to sqrt (n), then y in the range from sqrt (n - z^2) to z.

Answer (score 0):

You get a slightly faster solution with a bit of maths. X^2 modulo 4 is either 0 or 1, so the sum of 3 squares is 0 or 3 only if the three numbers are all even or all odd, which saves you three quarters of the work. Actually if n modulo 4 = 0, then you find all solutions by taking the solutions for n/4 and multiplying by 2.

We have a similar thing where x^2 modulo 9 is either 0, 1 or -1 depending on x modulo 3. So the sum cannot be +/- 4 modulo 9, a sum = +/- 3 implies all three variables are +/- 1 modulo 3.